# Format x-axis on chart created with pandas plot method

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

pandas.DataFrame.plot is a convenient method for plotting data from dataframes.  However, I don't understand how to format the axes using this method.  For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(index =  [datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 2, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 6, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 13, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 26, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 0, 0)],
                    data = {'total' : [5, 3, 1, 0, 2]})

df
```

Output

```
          total
2016-07-02  5
2016-08-06  3
2016-09-13  1
2016-10-26  0
2016-11-02  2
```

Now plotting with the pandas plot method:

```
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: example bar chart]

I would prefer that the x-axis just have the labels as the three-letter format of month - Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov.

Is this possible with the pandas plot method or should I build a chart with matplotlib instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a simpler way to change the x labels to month only.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(index =  [datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 2, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 6, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 13, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 26, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 0, 0)],
                    data = {'total' : [5, 3, 1, 0, 2]})

ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
x_labels = df.index.strftime('%b')
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)

plt.show()
```

[image: example chart]

Answer (score 10):

If you want to show the graph as a categorical bar plot, i.e. equidistant bars independent of the actual date, you can just reformat the xticklabels,

```
f = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%b')
ax.set_xticklabels([ f(x.get_text()) for x in ax.get_xticklabels()])
```

where `%b` is the month's abbreviated name  and ax is the axes of your plot.

Complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(index =  [datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 2, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 6, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 13, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 26, 0, 0),
                    datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 2, 0, 0)],
                    data = {'total' : [5, 3, 1, 0, 2]})

ax = df.plot(kind='bar')

f = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%b')
ax.set_xticklabels([ f(x.get_text()) for x in ax.get_xticklabels()])

plt.show()
```

[image]